# CanOpen communication (Python) 1 Slave and CAN-USB adapter

Tags: python, python-3.x, canopen

I am currently trying to implement simple communication between an I/O module as a CanOpen slave and my computer(Python script). The I/O module is connected to my computer with a PEAK USB-CAN adapter.

My goal would be to read or write the inputs/outputs. Is this even possible with the hardware, since I don't have a real "master" from that point of view?

Unfortunately I don't know what else I have to do to be able to communicate correctly with my I/O module.

```
import canopen
import time


network = canopen.Network()

network.connect(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000)


#add node and DCF File
IO_module = network.add_node(1, 'path to my DIO.DCF')
network.add_node(IO_module)

 
IO_module.nmt.state = 'RESET COMMUNICATION'  # 000h 82 01
print(IO_module.nmt.state)
time.sleep(5)

IO_module.nmt.state = 'OPERATIONAL'
print(IO_module.nmt.state)



for node_id in network:
     print(network[node_id])

IO_module.load_configuration()
```

i see some kind of communication in my console with timeout errors

```
INITIALISING
OPERATIONAL
<canopen.node.remote.RemoteNode object at 0x000002A023493A30>
Transfer aborted by client with code 0x05040000
No SDO response received
Transfer aborted by client with code 0x05040000
No SDO response received
```

Any advices ?

I can't get any further with the documentation alone
https://canopen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The good news is, you probably have all the required hardware. You are doing the "master" part from Python, that's fine. (The CAN bus isn't really master/slave, just broadcast. CANopen can be master/slave sometimes, but it's still all broadcast messages among equals on the same bus.)

You haven't provided information about your device, but I would start checking at a lower level.

Do you even have the CAN-Bus wired up correctly, and if so, what did you do to verify it? (Most common mistake: CAN-Bus not terminated with two 120ohm resistors. Though you usually can get away with just one instead of two.) And have you verified that you are using the correct baud rate?

The [library docu](https://canopen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nmt.html#examples) example suggests to wait for the heartbeat with `node.nmt.wait_for_heartbeat()`. Why are you using a sleep instead? If there is no heartbeat, you don't need to continue. (Unless the device docu says that it doesn't implement NMT heartbeat - would be unusual.)

I certainly wouldn't try to go ahead with SDOs if you cannot confirm a NMT heartbeat. Also, some devices don't implement SDOs but only PDOs.

Try sniffing the CAN bus at a lower level (e.g. not PDOs/SDOs but just print the raw messages received - from Python, or with a separate application - e.g. `candump` on Linux.) Try getting statistics of the CAN "network" interface (on Linux, e.g. `ifconfig`). If everything is okay, the adapter should be in state "ERROR-ACTIVE", and you should see the frame counter increase for frames you've sent via Python.

Comment: thanks for your fast response. here is what i have done so far:

-I checked the pinout of my IO module and my peak adapter. that should fit. 

- The terminating resistor is active on the I/O module, but not on the PEAK. This must be soldered. I will do that when I have time

-I saw in the DCF file that I was using the wrong baud rate in my Python script. I changed that to 500. However, nothing has changed yet.

[DeviceComissioning]
NodeName=DIO62-C
NodeID=1
NetworkName=NET1
NetNumber=1
Baudrate=500

-I replaced the sleep func. with the heartbeat func.. I get no answer.

Comment: Well it's hard to remote-debug these kind of issues, and StackOverflow isn't good for back-and-forth debugging, either. Just one more note, CAN has a feature where all devices will ACK every CAN packet on the bus. So it is possible to know, just from the CAN statistic counters after attempting to send a CAN frame, if the bus is working and has another device connected. (Even if the other device doesn't send any CAN frames yet.)

Comment: Hello, short feedback: I replaced my I/O module with another CanOpen device. The program and the adapter work so far with the other device. Maybe I can still find out why the I/O module isn't working. Many thanks for the help.